# Drag-Drop is not working for second xib file in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have created a tabview application in Cocoa. There is a mainmenu.xib file for main application. After that I created one more window (.xib file) in the same project. Now, I want to drag-drop for second dialog. I am trying to drag from second window and drop to AppDelegate.h file. But it is not dragging. What setting we need or any idea how drag and drop will work from second dialog to AppDelegate.h file.

Thanks,

Comment: Why or what would you want to drag and drop from a _.xib_ file to a code file? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have created a window in cocoa application and the resource file name is (mainMenu.xib file) and other file is appdelegate.h and appdelegate.mm. Now I have create one more .xib file using file->new->osx->user interface ->windows  call xib file as secondwindow.xib.
Now, I have created the one button on mainMenu.xib window and wrote the action on the button to when click on button the second xib window will call (that is working fine).
My question is now I want to make the secondwindow as model.
And Also I want to write some action on second window, then where we can write action.

Answer (score 1):

The "Custom Class" of the "File's Owner" placeholder in the xib needs to be your app delegate class to do what you want, in which case the app delegate will be acting as the window's owner.

It's possibly better to create a NSWindowController subclass to contain the code for the new xib, and have that class be the Custom Class and File's Owner of the Xib.